# How to detect down/up event of special keys on the keyboard

Tags: c#, c++, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, keyboard-events

My environment is Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 10 64bit.

In my Windows Store App(for Windows 8.1), I appended the keyboard event like this(This is a c++/cx program because I'm using C++ toolkit):

```
auto amv = Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::CoreApplication::MainView;
if (amv){
    auto cw = amv->CoreWindow;
    if (cw){
        cw->KeyDown += ref new TypedEventHandler<CoreWindow ^, KeyEventArgs^>(srt, &WinRTApp::OnKeyDown);
        cw->KeyUp += ref new TypedEventHandler<CoreWindow^, KeyEventArgs^>(srt, &WinRTApp::OnKeyUp);
    }
}
```

When I pressed a Hankaku key on my Japanese(109) keyboard. System triggers the KeyUp event with undefined VirtualKey code(243) and KeyDown event with code 244. And when I released that key, no event triggered.

Second press triggers KeyUp(244) and KeyDown(243), and second release has no trigger.

I want to detect KeyUp event exactly. Are there any good ways?

Answer (score -1):

I have looked into your question and found a fairly simple way to handle the key up event every time regardless of the character value. Inside the Onlaunched event you can add your event handler in the App.xaml.cpp or you can add it to the specific page eg. MainPage.xaml.cpp

```
Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::CoreApplication::MainView->CoreWindow->KeyUp += ref new Windows::Foundation::TypedEventHandler<Windows::UI::Core::CoreWindow ^, Windows::UI::Core::KeyEventArgs ^>(this, &KeyUpTest::App::OnKeyUp);
```

In the event handler itself simply use

```
void KeyUpTest::App::OnKeyUp(Windows::UI::Core::CoreWindow ^sender,       Windows::UI::Core::KeyEventArgs ^args)
{

}
```

This will fire every time non-system key up occurs. You can use the same process for multiple key states with a bool array.

More information can be found here: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/windows/117293/

There are a number of issues with the KeyUp and KeyDown commands is that they return the value of the key pressed but not the value of the character selected for example:

If I press 7 the response is 55 and if I press shift 7 the answer is still 55 and not the value of &. What you might be looking for is the CharacterReceived event which provides more context and handles casing and other values.

To add this event you can use

```
Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::CoreApplication::MainView->CoreWindow->CharacterReceived += ref new Windows::Foundation::TypedEventHandler<Windows::UI::Core::CoreWindow ^, Windows::UI::Core::CharacterReceivedEventArgs ^>(this, &KeyUpTest::App::OnCharacterReceived);
```

And the handler looks like:

```
void KeyUpTest::App::OnCharacterReceived(Windows::UI::Core::CoreWindow ^sender, Windows::UI::Core::CharacterReceivedEventArgs ^args)
{
    bool iskey = false;
    int keycode = args->KeyCode;

    if (keycode == 65) {
        iskey = true;
    }
}
```

I hope this was helpful.

Comment: There is no issue on alphabet keys. Hankaku key doen't work by that solution.